# What :=> means in data construtor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm reading https://matt.might.net/articles/cek-machines/ and it has this line  `data Lambda = Var :=> Exp`

How to read that?  What`:=>` means? I never saw this kind of arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the *name* of the data constructor as is specified in the [*Haskell report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.4):

```
consym  ->  (: {symbol | :})<reservedop>
```

Just like you can write:

```
data Lambda = Arrow Var Exp
```

or:

```
data Lambda = (:=>) Var Exp
```

Data constructors that work with a sequence of symbols always start with a colon (`:`).

Comment: Oh, so I can create infix constructors too, with arbitrary name as long as they start with :?

Comment: @geckos: yes, and given it is not a reserved operator, so `::` is not possible since that is a reserved operator, but `:::` is possible for example.

Comment: This is typically done to give items a more cleaner syntax. For example here, it looks like an arrow.

Comment: It's nice when defining expression syntax like `data Exp a = Var a | Exp a :+: Exp a | Exp :*: Exp a`

Comment: Cool! There is any rule like that "it has to start with :" for custom operators too?

Comment: @geckos: all data constructors that are operators should start with a colon yes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah but that <$> <|  <|> operators have to start with `<` for example?

Comment: @geckos: those are not data constructors, but functions. In that case these should *not* start with a colon. Just like data constructors with a name start with an uppercase, the symbol data constructors start with a colon. And just like a function starts with a lowercase, an operator that is not a data constructor does not start with a colon.

Comment: @geckos You can pretend that `:` is an "uppercase symbol", so it can be used for constructors, but not for other identifiers, like any name starting with `A`, for instance.

Comment: If you need a reminder why it's `:`, consider `(:)`, the simplest possible data constructor that begins with a `:` (it's a `:` followed by the empty string).